# Get next chunk of text (of specified size) contained in a macro

Tags: tex-core, boxes, expl3, split, box

Let's say we have a lot of text to be typeset contained in a single macro, let's call it `\myverylongtext`

```
\newcommand{\myverylongtext}{
    This is some really long text: \blindtext[4].

    And it continues even more: \blindtext[1].
}
```

For simplicity, let's say there is no sectioning/ newpage command in `\myverylongtext`, but it can have line-breaking commands, and multiple paragraphs (paragraph-breaking commands?). Also, assume that font size & leading remain constant throughout, though all other LaTeX typesetting commands (\textbf, etc) are allowed within the text & should take effect.

Is it possible to define an efficient* macro that (when encountered) gets the next chunk of text of specified dimension? For example:

```
\newcommand{\getnextchunk}[4]{
    % #1 is name of macro (in our case \myverylongtext) 
    % #2 width of text box
    % #3 height of text box in lines
    % #4 draftmode: optional boolean argument that, when set, instead of typesetting contents returns the actual height (in lines), and width (in length units) of the chunk. (useful in making dynamic layout decisions)
    % returns/typesets a box of shape width * height
}
```

New calls to this macro `\getnextchunk` should get next chunk of text, as if the text contained in `\myverylongtext` reflowed from previous chunk to this chunk.

* This `\myverylongtext` can be very long, and there can be numerous such chunks, so efficiency is needed. You cannot typeset remaining portion of `\myverylongtext` multiple times. One vision I have of solution for such problem is that a box of size 0 is filled iteratively till it grows to the specified metric: width (in length dimension), height (in lines), and required justification; though I lack understanding of low-level tex/luatex/expl3 to write it myself.

Also, either justification commands like raggedright/raggedleft/full-justified specified in `\myverylongtext` should magically take effect, or we can set a restriction that we won't have such commands in the `\myverylongtext` & instead pass it as a 4th argument to `\getnextchunk` (I think latter is preferable, and would make it either easier and/or cleaner to code/use).

Another way to visualize the problem is imagine that we have multiple rectangular text boxes (of different width and height) that flow into each other sequentially as we encounter them in our document (don't worry about placement of these text boxes, *tex already has multiple elegant solutions for that). Also, we don't know when and how many such text boxes will be encountered in the document upfront. In my opinion, from years of using *tex, solving just this one problem will open tons of possibilities, and make tex unbeatable (against InDesign, etc) in value as a typographic tool for design-oriented layouts. Tools like InDesign, and Affinity Publisher allow linking text boxes that eventually flow into each other as a stream, and is something indispensable for a typographic system that envisions to cater to modern expressive typography, and plurality of designs. That can open up *tex as a typesetter to a much broader typesetting/design community.

Comment: The `\vsplit` primitive does that.  I'll check whether there is a nice user interface.

Comment: Yep, `\vsplit` indeed does that, though afaik width of a split cannot be changed. I tried unvboxing to change the width, it doesn't work because at that point its a collection of hboxes with newly inserted hyphens. If you are thinking of typesetting a vbox, and continuously splitting it, it has to respect the new width of new chunk & ideally not retypest the entire remaining part of `\myverylongtext`, as typesetting a vbox is more than `O(n^2)` complexity in my experiments.

Comment: Is LuaTeX possible?

Comment: Yes LuaTex is allowed :)

Comment: magaz.sty does two or three typesettings to measure (count chunks). Also see truncate.sty

Comment: @HenriMenke I have a comment for you on the answer by wipet.

Comment: @reportaman I had a go at this when you first asked the question but I couldn't get it to work.  This is mainly because I don't really understand how to use the TeX paragraph builder correctly (`tex.linebreak` in LuaTeX).  I can never get anything usable out of it.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sure thanks :) I would imagine someone who understands how tex meets the page dimension goals, and geometry package would know the answer? This is because one way to imagine this question is that each box is a newpage, and given each page can have (afaik) new dimensions, and text still naturally reflows from previous page, it is indeed like linking textboxes of varying dimensions (which is what my question essentially is).

Comment: I think @topskip might have insights, since his speedata publisher seems to reflow text into varying box sizes, and it looks like it is using some part of luatex?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is not exactly what you want but all information is managed at one place. I hope, that it is not problem to accept three passes over parameters.

The data should look like this:

```
%          lines  width
\declchunk    5     10cm ;
\declchunk    6     12cm ;
\declchunk   12     13cm ;
\declchunk    9     10cm ;
\declchunk    9     10cm ;
\declchunk    9     10cm ;
\declchunk    7      8cm ;
\declchunk    5     10cm ;

\formatchunks \myverylongtext

\setbox101 = \getnextchunk
\setbox102 = \getnextchunk  \rebox 102:{\raggedright}
\setbox103 = \getnextchunk
\setbox104 = \getnextchunk  \rebox 104:{\raggedleft} 
\setbox105 = \getnextchunk

% you can place these boxes everywhere. the following code is only for testing:

box 101: \par \box101 \bigskip
box 102: \par \box102 \bigskip
box 103: \par \box103 \bigskip
box 104: \par \box104 \bigskip
box 105: \par \box105 \bigskip

\bye
```

First, we dcelare dimensions of all chunks (by number of lines for heights and by dimensions for widths). Second, we format the given text. Finally, we can get a pieces of the data and save them to boxes, for example. They are justified to blocks by default. If we need to do another setting, then we can re-box these boxes. Our example shows that second box is ragged right and fourth box is ragged left. Moreover, you can do

```
\vbox to<dimension>{\unvbox103} \vtop to12mm{\unvbox105} etc.
```

for example, because there is a stretchability and shrinkability between lines.

Implementation: we get all `\parshape` parameters by the list of `\declchunk`s, then we format text using these parameters (only once) to `\vbox\allchunks` and then we do `\vsplit` when `\getnextcunk` is called. Finally we can do a little re-boxing if user need somewhat different form block justification.

My implementation works with plain TeX and classical TeX only. We needn't any TeX extension and (of course) we need not LaTeX:).

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\newcount\shapenum
\newcount\globpar
\newbox\allchunks
\newif\ifrepeat

\splittopskip=\baselineskip

\def\formatchunks#1{\setbox\allchunks=\vbox{%
   \def\par{\ifhmode\shapepar\fi}
   \def\shapepar{\prevgraf=\globpar 
      \parshape\shapenum\shapelist \endgraf
      \globpar=\prevgraf
      \ifnum\prevgraf>\shapenum \let\par=\endgraf \fi}
   \dimen0=\baselineskip \baselineskip=\dimen0 plus2pt minus2pt
   \widowpenalty=0 \clubpenalty=0 \brokenpenalty=0
   \penalty0 #1\vfil}
   \setbox0=\vsplit\allchunks to0pt % \splittopskip added
   \expandafter \renewsize \sizelist \relax
}

\def\shapelist{} \def\sizelist{}
\splittopskip=\baselineskip

\def\shapelist{} \def\sizelist{}

\def\declchunk #1 #2;{\edef\sizelist{\sizelist#1\space}
   \tmpnum=0
   \loop  \advance\tmpnum by1 \advance\shapenum by1
          \edef\shapelist{\shapelist 0pt#2}%
          \ifnum\tmpnum<#1 \repeat
}
\def\getnextchunk{\vsplit\allchunks to\size
   \ifx\sizelist\empty \def\size{\baselineskip}%
   \else \expandafter \renewsize \sizelist \relax \fi 
}
\def\renewsize #1 #2\relax{%
   \def\size{#1\baselineskip}\def\sizelist{#2}%
}

\def\rebox#1:#2{\setbox#1=\vbox{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{}%
   \repeattrue
   \def\raggedright{\rightskip=0pt plus1fill minus1em \relax}%
   \def\raggedleft{\leftskip=0pt plus1fill minus1em \relax}%
   \hsize=\wd#1 
   \unvbox#1
   \loop
      \setbox2=\lastbox
      \ifvoid2 \repeatfalse
      \else \setbox0=\hbox{\hbox{\unhbox2}\penalty-10000 \unhbox0 }
            \unskip\unskip\unpenalty
      \fi
      \ifrepeat \repeat
   \null
   #2\noindent \hfil \unhbox0 \par
}}

\def\myverylongtext{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  ...
  purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.
  Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your other idea, I copied both pieces of your code (definitions precede calls to macros) into a .tex file and ran it using luatex/xetex/tex. All gave the same error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\declchunk ...elist {\sizelist #1\space } \tmpnum 
                                                  =0 \loop \advance \tmpnum ...`. Can you please mention what exact command are you using? And if I need to add anything to it?

Comment: @reportaman It was my fault: I missed first five lines from my code (\new... declarations) when I copied the code to this web site. Sorry. I correted it righ now.

Comment: Note: the copy of `! Undefined control sequence` error message cannot be done in comments here because it is compressed to one line. But the key information "what control sequence" is written at the edge of two lines in such message. In this case, the `\tmpnum` was the undefined control sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that it works. Its a little late here, I will get back tomorrow with more testing and/or questions. Also, even though the API/macro requested in the question (as you noted) is different, I did upvote your answer as this itself is very useful as a first step towards the API/macro requested in the question. Will keep the question/bounty alive for other closer implementation, hope that's ok by this forums guidelines (if there are any related guidelines).

Comment: One boundary case that I encounter is this: If the number of chunks declared (using \declchunk) is same as the number of chunks actually assigned to boxes (using \getnextchunk), then we get this Runaway argument error while executing last \getnextchunk: `Runaway argument?\n ! Paragraph ended before \renewsize was complete.\n <to be read again> \n \par  l.<no> box<no>: \par\n \box<no> \bigskip`.

Comment: Also, some comments would be great. For instance, do we actually need this: `\dimen0=\baselineskip \baselineskip=\dimen0 plus2pt minus2pt` And how did you choose 2pt? Is that based on font-size? For grid typesetting, I would assume one would replace 2pt with 0pt, right? The reason I ask is that I generally like to keep all dimensions some ratio of fontsize, that way similar looking results come out when fontsize is changed.

Comment: @reportaman I added a more test to the `\getnextchunk` macro. Bug `Runaway argument` fixed.

Comment: The `\baselineskip=\dimen0 plus2pt minus2pt` adds stretchability and shrikability. It is not used (i.e grid printing is default) when you don't ask to `\vox to<smething>{\unvbox103}`. But one of the typical requirement in Journal printing is to set the height of a column and sighlity stretch interline glue if the text is not full. So this possibility is ready, but you need not use it.

Comment: The dimension units (2pt) are almost irrelevant to the current font size. It influences only badness calculation and badness reporting when stretching is processed. Of course, shrinking is limited only to 2pt (overfull vbox is reproted if more shrinking is needed) but i mean that this is good value too.

Comment: Some more testing... When I used this code with latex quote environment it doesn't work. I wonder how one would achieve the effect of quote, such that the quote paragraph width is 80% of text width, and the quote is centered. I had been achieving that effect using quote environment, and redefining \rightmargin and \leftmargin. Also, we won't know the line number of such quotes upfront, so cannot add them to \declchunk.

Comment: @reportaman I don't using LaTeX, so I cannot test it, but maybe LaTeX quote envirnment opens and closes TeX group and does `\leftskip` `\rightskip` settings locally. Then you can try to add `\global` before `\globpar=\prevgraf`. If \LaTeX uses `\par` control sequnece to close its quote environment then ir may be work. Of course, we won't know the line numbers. But combination of macros which follows the task of this thread with classical macros seems sometimes quite absurd.

Comment: I just reran it by adding \global in front of \globpar=\prevgraf, it doesn't work. I mean the \leftmargin, \rightmargin get ignored. I wonder if you can think of a plain tex way of achieving that effect that would work with your code?

Comment: I looked into the file `latex.tlx` and I found that LaTeX redefines `\par` and `\parshape` parameters when `qoute` environment is used. I recommend: don't use LaTeX! Keep `\global` before `\globpar=\prevgraf` and try use plain TeX constructtion `{\leftskip=2em \rightskip=2em text...\par}`.

Comment: Thanks, that last suggestion of yours (`{\leftskip=2em \rightskip=2em text...\par}`) worked like magic :)  I was doing the same, but instead of `\par` I had a extra empty line (which generally denotes paragraph break?), though that had not worked. Adding that `\par` worked like magic. This is very interesting: where can I learn more about the basics of tex handling of boxes and vertical list? (in English)

Comment: I wrote (in these corona days) 24 pages summary of TeX principles. The document name is "TeX in nutshell" and it can be found at https://ctan.org/pkg/tex-nutshell .